# How implement a DSL for a matrix-lib in scala?

Tags: scala, dsl

I want to write a matrix library for my computer graphics projects. I want to use scalas dsl feature, to make it look and feel more naturaly. Can anybody give me a hint, where to find a simple tutorial that does *not* use external librarys? During my research I only found tutorials that use frameworks.

**Edit**

My question seemed to be not precise enough. I want to change that.
I am going to write a matrix-library. I know how to write a matrix-library.
I want to use the DSL-feature of scala. I don't know how to write a DSL in scala yet.
Please give me a hint where to find a good tutorial on DSL in scala, that does not use external librarys.
Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Would you like to get references for writing DSLs in Scala, or for writing matrix libraries?

Comment: If you already know which libraries do what you want, then why not to look at them? I'm pretty sure that you can find open-source ones. There is no better tutorial than working open-source code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*DSLs in Action* is a good source for it. If you want something more direct ( just a tutorial),then simple google queries point you to small tutorials on different ways to implement DSLs in scala or some libraries that have nice Scala DSLs. here are some:

http://www.scala-lang.org/node/1403
http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/DomainSpecificLanguages.html
http://jcranky.com/2010/06/01/dsl-in-scala-for-date-calculation/
http://engineering.foursquare.com/2011/01/21/rogue-a-type-safe-scala-dsl-for-querying-mongodb/
http://engineering.foursquare.com/2011/08/29/slashem-a-rogue-like-type-safe-scala-dsl-for-querying-solr/

After defining how your library should be ( or look), you can ask more precise questions on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

I'd look at what others are doing. For example, [Scalala](https://github.com/scalala/Scalala), which is a matrix library, or [Specs2](http://specs2.org), which has amazing DSLs.